# How to detect windows proxy settings after install4j v9.0

Tags: install4j

In our install4j installed application we use HttpClient (Apache) with "useSystemProperties" to perform http requests. Up until v9.0 of install4j that meant windows proxy settings were automatically applied. However, since 9.0.4 this no longer works (probably since 9.0.1 since proxy handling was reworked there, but I haven't been able to verify this). The installer itself still detects proxy settings (update check uses the proxy as before), but they are no longer "forwarded" to the installed application.

Is there a way to turn this "forwarding" back on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In install4j 9.0.1+ the proxy settings are no longer available as system properties.

On Windows, install4j 9.0.1+ uses native code, not Java sockets for HTTP requests. To force the use of Java sockets you can set the VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.noWinInetConnection=true
```

The auto-detected proxy that is used for the connection can then be obtained from

```
com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper.getProxyHostInfo(url)
```

Comment: Where should this be set? I tried setting it in the "VM Parameters" for the launcher in "Configure java invocation". But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but my answer was incomplete, I have just edited it.

Comment: And ProxyHelper will only return something useful if `-Dinstall4j.noWinInetConnection=true` is set, is that correct? And if so, would you consider a feature request for making the proxy settings available even when using native code in the installer? =)

Comment: No, ProxyHelper  will always return something useful, it just may not be the same that the native connection is using.

Comment: That worked perfectly. For future readers:
`-Dinstall4j.noWinInetConnection=true` makes install4j revert to java sockets, but it does not set the system properties for proxies like older versions of install4j.
`com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyHelper.getProxyHostInfo(url)` is an api where you can retrieve proxy settings the way install4j used (and do what you please with that information).
@Ingo please correct me if I got something wrong. Also, this isn’t really part of the public api of install4j is it? Can we assume it will remain (to the same extent as public api)?

Comment: Indeed, this is no part of the public API, but it is not likely to change.